# SuiteScript 2.0 and Constant variables

Tags: suitescript

I'm experienced in Suitescript 1.0 but need to use the new SFTP functionality.
I'd like to share the same constant variables across two or more javascript source routines.
In Suitescript 1.0 I used to put them in a library and attach it to the required scripts.

With Suitescript 2.0 I know this is not possible due to modules and the model it uses.
What is the best method to share the variables across multiple Suitescript 2.0 javascript routines?

Answer (score 4):

You can still use custom modules similar to libraries. If these values are constants and don't change you can use something like this

```
// Your File
define(['N/error', 'N/record', 'N/search', 'N/runtime', './Library.js'],
    function(error, record, search, runtime, myLibraryFile) {
        myLibraryFile.SHAREDCONSTANTS.YOURVARIABLE;
});

// Library.js
define(['N/error', 'N/record', 'N/search', 'N/runtime'],
function(error, record, search, runtime, myLibraryFile) {
    return {
        SHAREDCONSTANTS: {
            YOURVARIABLE: 'SOMEVALUE'
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches I can think of.

1) Create your own 2.0 module that contain the constants you want to carry across multiple 2.0 scripts.  Then require the new constant module in each of those scripts.

2) Create company level parameters that each of the script reads to obtain the constants.  This can be a parameter per or one parameter in a JSON blob to create multiple properties in one parameter.

Either way should get you were your going.

Answer (score -1):

```
function constant(value) {
  return () => {
    return value;
  }
}


var myConst = constant(10)
console.log(myConst())
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.